# Java Assignment, add value to variable in different class

Tags: java

currently doing an assignemnt but i'm new to programming so was wondering how you add a value to a variable in a different class which already has an existing class

```
    class OtherClass {
        int a;
    }
    public class Main Class{
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b = 7;
        OtherClass temp = new OtherClass();
        OtherClass.a = 5
        OtherClass.put(b) //this is where I'm not sure how to add b to a
}
```

Actual Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
System.out.print("Enter amount of money you have: "); 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
Wallet bettersWallet = new Wallet(); 
bettersWallet.moneyAvailable = input.nextDouble(); //then had a function which played out a bet and added/took away winnings from the bet 

 int winnings = 5;
 bettersWallet.moneyAvailable +=winnings; //Will setMoneyAvailable function work in this scenario aswell?
```

}

```
class Wallet {
    double moneyAvailable;
    double openingCash;
    public void setMoneyAvailable()
    {
        moneyAvailable += ChuckALuckDiceGame.winnings;
    }
```

Comment: error in your code, won't compile according to me. winnings is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
int b = 7;
OtherClass temp = new OtherClass();
temp.a = 5;
temp.a += b; //Same as temp.a = temp.a + b;
System.out.println(temp.a);
```

What we are doing here,
We are creating an object of class `OtherClass`, the name of the object is `temp`.
Then we are assigning the value 5 in the attribute `a` of object `temp`

Then we are adding the value of primitive variable `b` into the variable `temp.a`.

The sum of the above equation is being assigned to the value of `temp.a`

Then I am printing the sum at the end through `System.out.println(temp.a);`

Comment: That's what I had but for some reason the value wouldn't change

Comment: @MonoConman you might be doing temp.a + b. See I have written temp.a += b;

Comment: @MonoConman Basically when we add two variables, we also have to save it somewhere. so you could assign them like this temp.a = temp.a + b;

Comment: @MonoConman you have it a little bit wrong. you need to read about functions, by value, by reference, function parameters, etc. In your answer, i see chuckALuckGame.winnings but winnings is not a static variable. it is declared inside the main function, so it won't reach the setFunction at all, unless you send it as a parameter.